# C structure; overcoming passing a string to a char

Tags: c, char, structure

I am trying to print a simple structure, which does not work because I am trying to pass a string into a char (I know this is illegal). Yet I cannot figure out how to overcome this. I know there's a way with strcpy and without strcpy, how can I correct this? I have searched the forum and found similar questions, but was unable to apply them to my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct article
{
    int number;
    int quantity;
    char description[21];
};

void print(struct article *p)
{
    printf("Article Number: %d\nQuantity: %d\nDescription: %s", p->number, p->quantity, p->description);
}

int main()
{
    struct article *mydata;
    mydata->number = 333;
    mydata->quantity = 465;
    mydata->description = "Wall Street Journal\n";

    print(mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct article mydata = {
    333,
    465,
    "Wall Street Journal\n"
};

print(&mydata);
```

---

```
struct article mydata;
mydata.number = 333;
mydata.quantity = 465;
strcpy(mydata.description, "Wall Street Journal\n");

print(&mydata);
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are declaring a pointer to a `struct article`. You need to allocate memory for that pointer. It won't be allocated on the stack automatically for you. Using `malloc` you allocate dynamic memory to the heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    struct article *mydata = malloc(sizeof(struct article));

    if(article == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    mydata->number = 333;
    mydata->quantity = 465;
    char *description = "Wall Street Journal\n";
    size_t len = strlen(description);
    memcpy(mydata->description, description, len);
    mydata->description[len] = '\0';    
    print(mydata);
    free(mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `strcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this. But why do you need alternative ways if you have a function that can do the job for you.

```
char mydescription[]="Wall Street Journal\n";
int count =0 ;

for( count =0 ; mydescription[count] != '\0' ; count++)
{
    mydata->description[count] = mydescription[count] ;

}
```